# October CMS | How to get a property value from from component installed on specific page?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, octobercms, octobercms-backend

I created my component with an option "perPage", that acept an number and set the limit of works displayer per page...

[image]

```
public function defineProperties()
    {
        return [
            'perPage' => [
                'title' => 'Number os works per page',
                'description' => 'How many works do you want to display per page?',
                'default' => 9,
                'validationPattern' => '^[0-9]+$',
                'validationMessage' => 'Only numbers allowed'
            ],
            'sortOrder' => [
                'title' => 'Order of Works',
                'description' => 'How do you want to order the actors',
                'type' => 'dropdown',
                'default' => 'newest',
            ],
        ];
    }
```

It work's great with GET implementation... but on my project I need to implement AJAX everywhere, so I need to load pages via AJAX, and I need to know what the number was setted on a component... How I can get this number?

```
//my layout code
function onOpenWorkList()
{

    $this['works'] = Category::where('slug', input('slug'))->first();

    $this['categories'] = Category::all();

    $this['active_category'] = input('slug');

    $this['perPage'] = "";  // HERE IS THE CODE

    return [
        '.home_categories' => $this->renderPartial('work_list_categories_post'),
        '.container' => $this->renderPartial('work_list')
    ];
}
```

[image]

Comment: Paste code as text not image

Answer (score 0):

In your component file:

```
public $perPage;

/* ... */

public function init()
{
    $this->perPage = $this->property('perPage');
}
```

Then, in the layout, you can do this:

```
function onOpenWorkList()
{
    $this['works'] = Category::where('slug', input('slug'))->first();

    $this['categories'] = Category::all();

    $this['active_category'] = input('slug');

    $_component = $this->components['builderList']; // Get the component

    $this['perPage'] = $_component->perPage; // Get $perPage from component

    return [
        '.home_categories' => $this->renderPartial('work_list_categories_post'),
        '.container' => $this->renderPartial('work_list')
    ];
}
```

Personally, I would just put the `onOpenWorkList()` function into the component file (and not in the layout code) as it can still be accessed via ajax when it's in there just as easily, and then you wouldn't have to fetch the component as in the example above.

Comment: Hello, yeah I know about that.. but it's works inside of a component configuration file... And I need to get this value outside, I can't add this code on my layout code file :P

Comment: @IvanDunets Sorry, I misunderstood your initial question. I have updated my answer now.

Comment: I get an error ""Undefined index: worksList" on line 26 of A:\xampp\htdocs\framastudio\storage\cms\cache\50\74\default.htm.php" (worksList is a component's alias :) )

Comment: You probably need to pass data to the partials you're rendering. I recommend posting this as a new question with the relevant code as it's a separate issue.

Answer (score 0):

Getting a property from the Builder Component in the PHP area, should by used in the onEnd function:

```
    function onEnd()
    {
        $component = $this->page->components['builderDetails']->record
    }
```